# How to create vertically connected tree map via Echart

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

This code below is the example of treemap using Echart, what i expect is to order each series vertically and then connected to each series, then sizing by the data.

In this example, each series will randomly arrange by its size

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-disk

```
myChart.showLoading();
$.get(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/data/disk.tree.json', function (diskData) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  const formatUtil = echarts.format;
  function getLevelOption() {
    return [
      {
        itemStyle: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          gapWidth: 5
        }
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          gapWidth: 1
        }
      },
      {
        colorSaturation: [0.35, 0.5],
        itemStyle: {
          gapWidth: 1,
          borderColorSaturation: 0.6
        }
      }
    ];
  }
  myChart.setOption(
    (option = {
      title: {
        text: 'Disk Usage',
        left: 'center'
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function (info) {
          var value = info.value;
          var treePathInfo = info.treePathInfo;
          var treePath = [];
          for (var i = 1; i < treePathInfo.length; i++) {
            treePath.push(treePathInfo[i].name);
          }
          return [
            '<div class="tooltip-title">' +
              formatUtil.encodeHTML(treePath.join('/')) +
              '</div>',
            'Disk Usage: ' + formatUtil.addCommas(value) + ' KB'
          ].join('');
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Disk Usage',
          type: 'treemap',
          visibleMin: 300,
          label: {
            show: true,
            formatter: '{b}'
          },
          itemStyle: {
            borderColor: '#fff'
          },
          levels: getLevelOption(),
          data: diskData
        }
      ]
    })
  );
});
```

This is what I expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO6pL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell it is currently not possible. You can impact the shape of the regions via the [`squareRatio`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.squareRatio) property but I couldnt get it aligned vertically.

If you dont need to pan and zoom you could put one treemap for each categorie and adjust the [position](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.left) (eg. `left: '20%'`) and [size](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.width) (eg. `width: '25%'`) accordingly.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-disk&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWxgCeIWxA5GDllgLYCGITANFQrQuHRrCYBhAIIAVAKIBxAPIAlAJqwp_QegDuEACZgAFswBMAZgCk26ugA2WAGZhmAFhsC7saMANYJewgAYwBrYicue2wvOxxgEQiomJ1YRwA3LGjiEiRg4HtgHBymIIBzYzAAI3sAVywmAF0-WAgwTgBlOkdiJDKeAHVDE2I3AF8x5tSDLjAuHNT0JGFRZikARn5YdKj60YAGMdjvZZExJikzLZ26sQA2I8XkFfOpC2vdsTNx47tT1fEUjcH1uxHWAFZHt4li81uCQXtYOszFDof9XncEWIfk90WsAOxYsEADjGqUaglRS1SdAYzFY7G4vF-6Fh4mk8mU6lgACFbHZ9EZTOJLJ5Uo4XMwLPsxd5fP5AiFwrBItEsCzYPFEirkurxVhMtlSHkCkUSuVKmU2FhoE0Wm1Ot0xH1BsNheNJhqZnMFtDnmdmDzNi0boj1hYqX82UweVcQ58wfjI9Q8eIee946DYKSNTCA2ngZnEd9kxRUzH4UWxBDS3mATHMVWwYdc_76zzCU3YCXyZTfqhvLTzgzODx-dRoxzFKoNBJxxRBSMRdZ5w5nK5xOC7rK7PKAkEwkk1RqtRwjylvBkskRjflCsVSEwrexbc1Wu0OF1aD1kP0QEMhVGCYpm8b15lIXFJ2DbYE1gHE_XLCQ4xgrMzBbSD80kDMUMRB5W0QwscOrHMMPrCRKyI4gzBRfDJ0bSjYAsSENQpahIwHOwh3pa0mVXHxMKnLkNAAET4xdhSYdZtz4iUNyYYkzB3Cc_H3JVzz1bxT3UjUryNXI7zNR8ii4aAygaN8HU_J1ej_AClw9EC7DA300WjYToNDMQk1ozDhOQzywQATlrNtzmE7CAqRGjSLCwjIvWdYQvLYSKMi-DXN8-jIuCljKXICkxgAbiAA) is an example:

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'treemap',
      name: 'CATEGORY A',
      width: '23%',
      left: '4%',
      nodeClick: false,
      roam: false,
      levels: [{color: ['lightblue'], itemStyle: {gapWidth: 4}}],
      data: [
        {name: 'A1', value: 40},
        {name: 'A2', value: 6},
        {name: 'A3', value: 24},
        {name: 'A4', value: 15},
        {name: 'A5', value: 12},
        {name: 'A6', value: 4},
        {name: 'A7', value: 18}
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'treemap',
      name: 'CATEGORY B',
      width: '23%',
      left: '30%',
      nodeClick: false,
      roam: false,
      levels: [{color: ['lightgreen'], itemStyle: {gapWidth: 4}}],
      data: [
        {name: 'B1', value: 13},
        {name: 'B2', value: 17},
        {name: 'B3', value: 8},
        {name: 'B4', value: 24},
        {name: 'B5', value: 15},
        {name: 'B6', value: 10},
        {name: 'B7', value: 24}
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'treemap',
      name: 'CATEGORY C',
      width: '23%',
      left: '56%',
      nodeClick: false,
      roam: false,
      levels: [{color: ['green'], itemStyle: {gapWidth: 4}}],
      data: [
        {name: 'C1', value: 4},
        {name: 'C2', value: 20},
        {name: 'C3', value: 6},
        {name: 'C4', value: 18},
        {name: 'C5', value: 22},
        {name: 'C6', value: 35},
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'treemap',
      name: 'CATEGORY D',
      width: '16%',
      left: '82%',
      nodeClick: false,
      roam: false,
      levels: [{color: ['orange'], itemStyle: {gapWidth: 4}}],
      data: [
        {name: 'D1', value: 7},
        {name: 'D2', value: 19},
        {name: 'D3', value: 12},
        {name: 'D4', value: 11},
        {name: 'D5', value: 4},
        {name: 'D6', value: 9},
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```